# Android - Writing string to file

Tags: android, storage, fileoutputstream, data-management

I took this code from [Android Developers page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) but the code won't work.
I've looked around but nobody seems to give a clear answer.

```
private void writetofile(String FILENAME, String content){

    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        //The problem is here ↓
      outputStream = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The "openFileOutput" is apperently undefined.
How do i write my code to make it write to the file and not fail to compile?

Here is my full code (if that helps)

```
public class HastighetFragment extends Fragment {
int color;
Button bAdd;

private void writetofile(String FILENAME, String content){

    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
      outputStream = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hastighet, container, false);
    bAdd = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    color=0;

    bAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(color){
        case 0:
            bAdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstylered);
            color=1;
            break;
        case 1:
            bAdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstylegreen);
            color=0;

            break;
        }
    }});

    return rootView;
}
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.app.FragmentManager FragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    FragmentManager.popBackStack();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The "openFileOutput" is apperently undefined. How do i write my code to make it write to the file and not fail to compile?

`openFileOutput()` is a method on `Context` and its subclasses.

> Here is my full code (if that helps)

Inside a `Fragment`, you can call `getActivity()` to retrieve the `Activity` that hosts the `Fragment`. `Activity` inherits from `Context`, and so you can call `openFileOutput()` on the `Activity`.

Comment: @HultBullt: Um, it would look like Java code. `getActivity()` is a method on `Fragment` that returns an `Activity`. `openFileOutput()` is a method on `Activity`. So, `getActivity().openFileOutput()` would call `openFileOutput()` on the `Activity` returned by `getActivity()`.